# In .NET 2.0 environment how to find which all objects are accessed/modified by a method

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a big C# application - .NET 2.0 - close to 70 projects in it.

I need to know the list of all objects a particular method accesses/modifies during the course of its execution.

That particular method is a starting point of a certain operation started by GUI. Based on the count user inputs, this method is called that many times in a loop to do that particular operation with only difference that in each iteration it sorts a particular input data list randomly and solution differs - least cost solution is chosen.

I want to run it in parallel using multiple threads.. currently my application does not use more than 25% CPU on quad core machine... that is only one thread is there and it can not take more than CPU .. therefore 25%... I want to run maximum as many threads as CPU count so that 100% utilization can be achieved and results come faster.

I have already created the threads but it occasionally keep crashing and exception text is not useful at all to know what happened.. all i know its due to multiple threads.

Once i know all objects it touches i can do further analysis on whether to put lock or provide individual copy of data to each thread where possible.

Comment: `C#` - `how to find all global variables` - What?????

Comment: What are global variables? C# ain't C/C++... You need to look for any object instances that are processed by a thread and which can possibly be processed by any other thread. It doesn't matter where those objects were coming from, it just matters that the threads are touching them -- that means, even an object from a private member variable must be considered if it is touched by any of your thread worker methods...

Comment: i have to either go line by line through complete execution path and find which all objects from outside the scope of my thread method are touched by it and methods inside it... which is going on and will take several days or week... therefore i was wishing if some one can suggest a smart and quick way for getting a list of that... may be some GC & related calls can help in some way...

Comment: It's not a question of .NET 2.0. It's a question of your Visual Studio version. I recommend that you open the solution with Visual Studio 2013 with ReSharper, and use the various features, like Code Map, Call Hierarchy and Inspect Value Origin/Destination.

Comment: I also suggest that you break up that solution - break off some class libraries, at least for the purpose of analysis. 70 projects is difficult to reason about.

Comment: To continue with what John said, if you only need to do it once ReSharper has a 30 day trial so you don't even need to pay anything (however you may end up liking resharper and buying it anyway, thats what happened to me :) )

Comment: Thanks .. will try ReSharper.